# Multi level header structure WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, header, multi-level

I need to make a header structure preview in WPF. I have looked into using StackPanels and DockPanels and can't seem to grasp exactly what is need. I also need a programmatic way of creating the header structure as it is created based on information provided by the user.

I need something to look like this:

|----------Superheader-----------|
|--------Header---------|-Header-|
|-Subheader-|-Subheader-|--------|

My main issue using StackPanels and DockPanels was that they would only take the minumum space and not fill to match the superheader width.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the `DataGrid` control ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx))?

You could create a class to hold your headers. For example:

```
public class BiologicalClassification
{
    public string Kingdom { get; set; }
    public string Phylum { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Genus { get; set; }
    public string Species { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could store all your header data in a `List<BiologicalClassification>` in your code-behind or view model.

Then you could display this data in a `DataGrid` using a binding:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BiologicalClassifications}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          GridLinesVisibility="None">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kingdom" Binding="{Binding Kingdom}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phylum" Binding="{Binding Phylum}" />
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This would ensure that your super-header (in this example, Kingdom) would always be a constant width. Same with the remaining headers.

Comment: The only problem is that I need it to be programmatically set rather than via XAML.

Comment: You mean you need to programatically set the column names? Or just the data?

Comment: I mean I need to have the number of columns and headers set programmatically as well as the text inside each value. I also have to set the bindings programmatically. I may not be fully grasping what you are saying to do I guess.

Comment: I see...it's definitely trickier if the number of columns is not fixed. One thing you could do is set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` (and remove the `DataGrid.Columns` section). It limits flexibility somewhat, but it could work in this case.

Comment: We found a workaround. We collected every column, column span, and row for each superheader, header, and subheader. Than we just added them one by one where they needed to be. A little hackish, but it got the job done for now.